# phoresistor vactrol tremolo noise

Tags: led, audio, analog, opto-isolator, photoresistor

I made an optocoupler by shrink tubing a generic photo resistor and a cold white led.

Then used it in the following setup to be able to control audio level to achieve tremolo effect:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMI21b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However with each LED blink a brief noisy crunch is heard. I have no idea, but it almost seems that photoresistor generates a small spike of current. Can this be true? Why does that happen and how can I prevent it?

Unfortunately I don't own an oscilloscope, so I can't confirm my theory

Comment: You should first verify that **no DC** exists on the Analog_in / Analog_out line. It should be zero volts when measured with a DC voltmeter. There are other causes of a transient as well as this one.

Comment: Also - you may not own an oscilloscope, but you're dealing with audio frequencies, so a soundcard is all the oscilloscope you need :)

Comment: `cold white LED` ..... that is an UV LED with a white phosphor strip ..... it is difficult to say how a photo resistor responds to that ..... try using an LED that does not use phosphor to generate light  ...... also, you are missing a resistor that is required to produce a voltage divider